# Metric on$ L_p(0,1),\, 0<p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm stuck with a homework exercise from my functional analysis class:

Let $0<p<1$. Prove, that $d_p(f,g) := \int_{(0,1)} |f(x)-g(x)|^p dx$ is a metric on $L_p(0,1)$, the space of all (equivalence classes of) measurable complex functions defined on (0,1).

$d_p(f,g) \ge 0$ is obvious, as well as $d_p(f,g) = 0  \Leftrightarrow f=g$ and $d_p(f,g) = d_p(g,f)$. Therefore only $d_p(f,g) \le d_p(f,h) + d_p(h,g)$ is left to show. I already read somewhere that it can be shown by using the generalized Minkowski Inequality, but I just don't know how. I would be glad if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $0<p<1,$ then $(x+y)^p \le x^p+y^p$ for all $x,y\ge 0.$ You can prove this by fixing $x,$ and considering the two functions of $y$ given by the left and right sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Since $d_p(h,h)=0$ you can add $h(x)-h(x)$ it in the integral and use the fact that $|x+y|^p\leq|x|^p+|y|^p$.